# Replacing words with regex in VBA

Tags: regex, vba

In each cell of column “A” on tab “Trial” I would like to replace every word “blue” with “white”, **except where there is a word “one” before “blue”**.
For that purpose, I have tried to apply a regex with negative lookahead. I have created the following code, but I am receiving an application-defined or object-defined error.
Could you please help me what causes the problem?

```
Sub Replace_test()
Dim regex As Object
Dim r As Range, rC As Range

Sheets("Trial").Activate
Set r = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regex.Pattern = "(?<!one)\s\blue"


For Each rC In r
    If rC.Value <> "" Then rC.Value = regex.Replace(rC.Value, " white")
Next rC
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `(?<!one)` is a negative *lookbehind* which is not supported by VBScript.RegExp. You could replace `one blue` with a placeholder, replace `blue` then replace back the placeholder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your explanation.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested and it worked.